# Big table in latex with multicolumn and multirow

Tags: tables

I need someone to help me create the following table in latex.
[image]

Comment: Is this table really filled with the same 12 numbers in each row? If not, over which range might the numbers vary?

Comment: @ALRADDADI did the answer below meet your requirement -- if so please consider to accept and upvote

Answer (score 3):

Please try and upload some code you have tried so as to showcase your effort else the entire data has to be punched in

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{makecell, caption, booktabs, multirow, siunitx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\cellalign{lc}
\newcommand{\otoprule}{\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}[tp]

  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
  \caption{VSI Parameters}
  \label{tab:2}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{@{}
                  *{6}{c}
                  % *{12}{c}
                  % >{$}c<
                  % {$}
                  % @{\hskip1.5em}
                  % S[table-format=1.4]
                  % S[table-format=1.1]
                  @{}}
    \toprule
    phi
      &model
        &F1
          &Y1 
            &Y1 
              &Y1\\                   \cmidrule(lr){4-4}\cmidrule(lr){5-5}\cmidrule(lr){6-6}

      &
        &
          &50 100 500 1000
            &  50 100 500 1000
              & 50 100 500 1000\\        \midrule
    0.1
      &Normal
        &N
          &50 100 500 1000
            &50 100 500 1000
              &50 100 500 1000\\          

      &
        &E
          &50 100 500 1000
            &50 100 500 1000
              &50 100 500 1000\\
      &
        &E
          &50 100 500 1000
            &50 100 500 1000
             &50 100 500 1000\\
      &
        &E
          &50 100 500 1000
            &50 100 500 1000
              &50 100 500 1000\\
      &
        &E
          &50 100 500 1000
            &50 100 500 1000
              & 50 100 500 1000\\                                  \midrule        
      \vdots\\ 
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: +1. I would change `\cmidrule(lr){6-6}` to `\cmidrule(l){6-6}`, though, as no right-hand clipping is needed (or desirable).